# Date/time field out of range in Postgresql, hour field has more than 24 hours

Tags: postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import a .csv file into a Postgres Database. One of the fields is 'Simple throughput time', with the format HH:mm:ss. However, all of these values are greater than 24:00:00, which seems to be the highest value for the data type, therefore, when I try to import such file I get the value out of range error.

```
date/time field value out of range: "384:00:00"
```

How can I import it then? The file has close to 10.000 rows, so I don't think I can change the format in the file. Is there any other type of data type I can change the column to?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You might want an `interval`.

Comment: @stickybit you are right! That worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to store is neither a time or a date but an interval of time.
Therefore, you should use the `interval` type.
[image]
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html